# Multi-layer repeated measure - mixed models?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have 250 subjects, divided in three groups (different medical conditions).

For each subject I have concentrations from three 'areas' (nested) at 5 timepoints.

subject 1, condition A, area X, timepoint 1, concentration * 
subject 1, condition A, area X, timepoint 2, concentration * 
etc 
subject 1, condition A, area Y, timepoint 1, concentration * 
subject 1, condition A, area Y, timepoint 2, concentration * 
etc 
subject 2, condition B, area X, timepoint 1, concentration * 
etc etc etc

I'm interested in concentration changes over time and differences between groups (medical conditions), how best to approach this?

I'm a dummy, so please explain as simple as possible, preferably with SPSS :)

Answer (score 0):

Repeated measures ANOVA, with condition and area as between-subject variables, and timepoint as within-subject variable

Comment: Thank you! That seems much easier than initially thought. Why a repeated measure ANOVA rather than a mixed model? I thought concentration is nested within area is nested within condition/subject? And would it change if I have some missing data?